# Wait till site is created in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-collection

I am using below command to create a new site in SharePoint Online. This command works but it does not wait until the site is created. Is there a way I can run this in synchronously and get the site object in return.

```
$Site = New-SPOSite -Url $Url -Title "Site Title" -Owner $Admin -LocaleID 1033 -Template $SiteTemplate -StorageQuota $storageQuota -NoWait
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing the command without the `-NoWait` switch will make the script wait until the site is created.

```
New-SPOSite -Url $Url -Title "Site Title" -Owner $Admin -LocaleID 1033 -Template $SiteTemplate -StorageQuota $storageQuota

Get-SPOSite -Identity $Url
```